# IndexOutOfBoundsException when adding to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm gettgin `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3` exception when calling `list.add(location, item);` JavaDoc for the add method says that:

> If the location is equal to the size of this List, the object is added
>   at the end.

I am totally confused since it also says that `IndexOutOfBoundsException` should be thrown when `location < 0 || location > size()` but even in the exception location and size are equal.

**EDIT:** I copy-paste full javadoc here, to see what makes me uncomfortable about this.

`public abstract void add (int location, E object)`

Added in API level 1

Inserts the specified object into this List at the specified location. The object is inserted before the current element at the specified location. If the location is equal to the size of this List, the object is added at the end. If the location is smaller than the size of this List, then all elements beyond the specified location are moved by one position towards the end of the List.

Parameters

- location - the index at which to insert.
- object - the object to add.

Throws

- UnsupportedOperationException - if adding to this List is not supported.
- ClassCastException - if the class of the object is inappropriate for this List.
- IllegalArgumentException - if the object cannot be added to this List.
- IndexOutOfBoundsException - if location < 0 || location > size()

**EDIT #2**: Requested actual code:

```
Date newDate = sourceDateFormatter.parse(newTime.getDate());
Date date;
int insert = -1;
do {
    insert++;
    date = sourceDateFormatter.parse(list.get(insert).getDate());
} while(date.compareTo(newDate) < 0);

list.add(insert, newTime);
```

Comment: if the size is 3 the max element is at pos 2

Comment: There is no need to specify an `index` if you want to append with a `List`, just call `list.add(item);`

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa If i add it to pos2, the element at pos2 will be pushed to pos3, thats not what I want. I want to add it as a last element.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This add is located inside a loop that determines at what position the new item should be in the list, thats why I want it that way. Only problem is that it throws this exception when I want to add it to the end of the list, as the javadoc says.

Comment: Show us the actual code you are using. I have no problem when I call `list.add( list.size(), newitem )` where `list` is an ArrayList instance.

Comment: @FredK I've added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I posted my method I've noticed the problem. For whatever reason my logcat points to the `.add(index, object);` method when I click on the link, but in reality it is the `.get(index);` that throws the exception, and that perfectly makes sense.

Made a bit of a tweaking, now this code works as intended:

```
Date newDate = sourceDateFormatter.parse(newTime.getDate());
Date date;
int insert = 0;
do {
    date = sourceDateFormatter.parse(list.get(insert).getDate());
} while(date.compareTo(newDate) < 0 && ++insert < list.size());

list.add(insert, newTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and Lists in Java are 0 indexed. So if your size is 3, you have items at positions 0, 1 and 2. Your if condition should be

```
location < 0 || location >= size()
```

Comment: That's not MY if condition, I copy-pasted it from the .add method's javadoc. If I add it to position 2, the object that was in pos2 gets pushed to pos3.

Answer (score 0):

Well you actually are or giving a wrong location with non-zero based or probably just miss-using the indext at all, see java Lists are 0 based so if the size is 3 the last index should be 2 (0,1,2), just do one of these:

```
list.add(location-1, item);
```

or

```
list.add(item);
```

And you should do fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the new object before the first item, it would be:

```
list.add(0, item);
```

If you want the new object is before the n th item, it would be

```
list.add(n-1, item);
```

If you want to insert as the last item,

```
list.add(item);
```

Comment: As I read the javadoc for the method, `list.add(n, item);` should add item as last. Check my edit to question.

Comment: What is exactly class of "list" ?

Comment: List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add("AAA");list.add(1, "BBB");       It works, as I used java.util.ArrayList and java.util.List